# ¿Cómo recuperar variable de sesión desde diferentes secciones de proyecto Laravel?

Tags: laravel, session

Necesito declarar una variable de session en el método ej: index del controlador x y poder recuperar dicha variable desde el método ej: store del controlador y, intenté hacerlo a través de:

```
session(['variable_x' => 'Algún texto']);
```

E intentar recuperar dicho valor desde el controlador 'y' de la siguiente manera:

```
$variable_guardar = session('variable_x');
```

Pero ésto me devuelve como si la variable estuviese vacía, la pude recuperar con su valor asignado desde el mismo método y controlador en donde se crea, pero no de manera global desde otro controlador. ¿Cómo podría hacer que la declaración de esa variable de haga de manera global para que sea asequible desde cualquier controlador?

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Te aconsejo usar una Cookie. Puedes hacerlo de una manera muy sencilla.

Guardar la Cookie:

```
\Cookie::queue('nombre', 'valor', 15*24*60); // Ejemplo de tiempo: 15 días
```

Obtener la Cookie:

```
\Cookie::get('nombre');
```

Borrar la Cookie:

```
\Cookie::queue(\Cookie::forget('nombre'));
```

Espero que te sirva! Un saludo

Comment: Podría serme útil, más sin embargo me surge la duda si el usuario puede bloquear o modificar dicha cookie, ya que los datos que requería manejar a través de una variable de session son de vital importancia para la funcionalidad de la aplicación, y de ser eliminada o bloqueada la aplicación no funcionaría